# How to get all Maven plugins & their versions for a specific phase?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Do you know of a way to list all Maven plugins (with their versions) that are going to be executed for a particular phase? This should include all plugins set in all parents of the current project.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to run:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

That will show you the projects POM after interpolation and inheritance have been applied. It should be fairly easy to look in the build configuration and determine the configured plugins for a phase from there.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks. Although this helps, the effective-pom does not show all plugins for a specific phase. For example, I can see the maven-clean-plugin, and the maven-compiler-plugin in it, but that does not tell me which one is going to be executed in, say, the "clean" phase. Now, I know that it is going to be the "maven-clean-plugin", but this is not visible in the effective-pom xml.